# InterlockedIncrement parameter

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, atomic

I noticed that `LONG InterlockedIncrement(LONG* p)` not only returns the  increment, but also increments the value at the address of `p` itself. Which means, that as caller, you can use both the return-value, as well as the value pointed to by `p`.

This is fine, in fact, I can use this very well, but it is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-interlockedincrement).

Is it okay to use the modified value? Would this behavior be something that could be changed in a future version of the Windows API

Comment: That is not possible, it is not LONG**.  Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, you did not provide any.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not claiming anything, I'm trying to understand what I see.

Comment: @Ben so you're calling `InterlockedIncrement(p)` and you see that the pointer `p` that you pass as an argument gets incremented (the pointer itself, not the value it points to)!? How exactly do you observe that?

Comment: If you mean the *value* pointed to by `p` is incremented, then that's what `InterlockedIncrement` does. It then returns that value, as the documentation says: *InterlockedIncrement returns the incremented value.* You may not read the value pointed to by `p` directly, because that would be a race condition, which this function is designed to solve in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel No, not the address, but the value at the address the pointer refers to.

Comment: I added some additional info to the topic for clarity (and to prevent downvotes :) )

Comment: @Ben well but that should not be a surprise since that's exactly what `InterlockedIncrement` is supposed to do: increment the value that the argument points to!? Also, note the comment by @rustyx

Comment: *"Which means, that as caller, you can use both the return-value, as well as the value pointed to by `p`."* - No, you cannot. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-interlockedincrement) also mentions this: *"`InterlockedIncrement` is atomic only with respect to other `InterlockedXxx` calls."* Accessing the value through the pointer is going to introduce a data race, the one you tried to solve by using the `InterlockedXxx` API.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I'm afraid I didn't write the question clear enough for everybody to understand. Please note the ansers below for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual value in the memory location gets incremented but trying to read it afterwards would not be atomic, something else might have modified the value after the function returns but before you read from the memory address.

The return value is the incremented value on any recent system but it did not always work like this. Windows 95 & NT 3.x will run on 386 processors and those processors do not have the `LOCK XADD` instruction. On those systems the function did `LOCK INC` and [only returned the sign of the result](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040506-00/?p=39463).

This was perhaps most famously observed with `IUnknown::Release` and is part of the reason its return value is documented as "for debugging purposes only".

Answer (score 5):

> Which means, that as caller, you can use both the return-value, as well as the value pointed to by `p`.

No you cannot. The return value contains the incremented value after this call to `InterlockedIncrement`. On the other hand, if you read the variable `*p` then another thread may have, in the meantime, modified the value.